# Using Tkinter, how does one populate a combobox in a child window from a DB?

Tags: tkinter, toplevel

I have a Tkinter based program with a main window containing a menu. In the Main window I have a combobox which gets populated from a DB Table in SQLite3. If a selection is made in the Main Window Menu it brings up a child (Toplevel) window (DateWindow) containing a combobox and two DateEntry widgets.(See:Run expense report by category and date range). Now, my

- first problem

is that in the Main Window I have no problem populating the combobox but I cannot get the combobox in the DateWindow to populate from the same source in the SQLite DB. My

- second problem

is that after selecting the start and end dates in the two DateEntry widgets, how do I "transfer" their values to the Main Window to run a report? I am showing only the relevant code for the problems.

Your usual kind help will be appreciated.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
import sqlite3
import datetime as dt
import time
from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from prettytable import MSWORD_FRIENDLY
import subprocess, sys

"""Create a child window to get the category and dates"""

class DateWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(DateWindow,self).__init__()

        conn= sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/NedCard')
        cur=conn.cursor()

        query=cur.execute("SELECT IncCat from Analyse where Indicator ='E' ")
            
        data=[]

        for row in cur.fetchall():
            data.append(row[0])
            #print(row[0])
        #return data
            
        cur.close()
        conn.close()       

        # global tAnalysis

        # tAnalysis=tIncAnalyse
        
        self.geometry("500x150")
        self.title("Get  dates for report: " )

        #global c_Category

        self.l_select_cat=tk.Label(self,text='Category',fg='blue')
        self.l_select_cat.grid(row=2, column=0,sticky='w',pady=3,padx=5)
        self.c_select_cat=ttk.Combobox(self,width=20)
        #self.c_select_cat['values']=data()
        
        self.c_select_cat.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='news',pady=3)

        #self.c_Category=self.c_select_cat.get()
            

        self.l_Start_Date=tk.Label(self,text="Enter the start date for report", fg="blue")
        self.l_Start_Date.grid(row=4,column=0, sticky="w", padx=5, pady=10)
        self.d_Start_Date = DateEntry(self,width=10,fg="white",Locale='en_US',date_pattern='yyyy-mm-dd')
        self.d_Start_Date.grid(row = 4, column=1,sticky="w",pady=3)
        
        
        self.l_End_Date=tk.Label(self,text="Enter the end date for report", fg="blue")
        self.l_End_Date.grid(row=6,column=0, sticky="w", padx=5)
        self.d_End_Date = DateEntry(self,width=10,fg="white",Locale='en_US',date_pattern='yyyy-mm-dd')
        self.d_End_Date.grid(row = 6, column=1,sticky="w",pady=3)

        self.b_Run_Report=ttk.Button(self, text="Run Report", width=10,command=Run_Report_By_Spend_Cat)
        self.b_Run_Report.grid(row=7,column=2, sticky="e", pady=10) 

"""Create a Menu for making selections"""
class Menu_ex():

    def __init__(self,parent):    
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.menubar=Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=self.menubar)

        fileMenu=Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        
        
        fileMenu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.onExit)
        fileMenu.add_command(label='Add a new Item', command=self.open_window)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=fileMenu)

        reportMenu=Menu(self.menubar,tearoff=0)
        
        
        reportMenu.add_command(label='Show all Income', command=Run_income_rpt)
        reportMenu.add_command(label='Income Analysis')
        reportMenu.add_separator()
        reportMenu.add_command(label='Show all Expenses', command=Run_expenses_rpt)
        reportMenu.add_separator()

        sub_menu=Menu(reportMenu,tearoff=0)
        sub_menu.add_command(label='Run expense spend by category',command=Run_Report_By_Spend_Cat)
        sub_menu.add_command(label='Run expense report by category and date range',command=self.Open_DateWindow)
        sub_menu.add_command(label='Run expense report by supplier')
        sub_menu.add_command(label='Run expense report by customer and date range')

        reportMenu.add_cascade(label='Expenses Analysis',menu=sub_menu)
        reportMenu.add_separator()
        reportMenu.add_command(label='Exit',command=self.onExit)

        self.menubar.add_cascade(label='Reports',menu=reportMenu)

    def onExit(self):

        self.parent.destroy()

    def open_window(self):
        self.window = Window(self)
        self.window.grab_set()


    def Open_DateWindow(self):

        self.window=DateWindow(self)
        self.window.grab_set()


"""Create main window"""

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):    
        super().__init__()
        
        global format_date
        date = dt.datetime.now()
        format_date=f"{date:%Y-%m-%d}"
        print(format_date)
        self.title('My Nedbank Credit Card')
        self.geometry('1150x450')
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(width=False,height=False)
        self.menu = Menu_ex(self)

def Expense_values_input(): 

    """ Populate the Expenses analysis combobox"""

    conn= sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/NedCard')
    cur=conn.cursor()

    query=cur.execute("SELECT IncCat from Analyse where Indicator ='E' ")
    
    data=[]

    for row in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(row[0])
        print(row[0])
    return data
    
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


self.e_ExpAnalyse_Exp=ttk.Combobox(self.l_Income, width=30)
    self.e_ExpAnalyse_Exp.grid(row=6, column=7, padx=5,pady=15, sticky='news')
    self.e_ExpAnalyse_Exp['values']=Expense_values_input()
    self.e_ExpAnalyse_Exp.current(newindex=None)
    self.e_ExpAnalyse_Exp.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',Comboclick)
    self.e_ExpAnalyse_Exp.bind('<FocusOut>',get_data_to_save)
    self.e_ExpAnalyse_Exp.config(state='disabled')
```

Comment: *I cannot get the combobox in the DateWindow* You can access it in your DateWindow via `self.master.e_ExpAnalyse_EXP`. I am sorry to tell, but you have a lack of basic knowledge in python programming. You should look for a toturial that explains you the concept of **OOP** in python. Even if it looks boring in the first place, you can do fancy stuff with it.

Comment: You haven't set the `values` option of the `Combobox` inside `DateWindow`.  Try adding `self.c_select_cat['values'] = data`.

Comment: Atlas435. Yes I agree about the basic knowledge which I often struggle to understand. Only after many attempts to understand a problem do I turn here for help. acw1668, the reason for not setting the values is because I get the following message."TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" if I do. Thank you both for your comments.

Comment: Did you notice my suggestion has no `()` after `data`?